# Forced Conversion from AzureRM to AZ powershell

Tags: azure, powershell, az

We have found that our AzureRM scripts have started to fail with Request to a Error downlevel service failed. This has forced us to change our scripts to start using the AZ powershell module, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/azure/new-azureps-module-az?view=azps-1.6.0. The conversion has worked really well except I haven't found the replacement for New-AzureWebsiteJob. Has anyone else run into this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For `New-AzureWebsiteJob` cmdlet, there is no direct equivalent in the Az or ARM PowerShell Cmdlets.

You can follow this [blog](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Deploying-a-WebJob-using-PowerShell-ARM-Cmdlets) to achieve your purpose, and note that if you are using Az powershell module, please modify ARM Powershell to Az powershell respectively.

Sample code for Az powershell like below:

```
#Resource details :
$resourceGroupName = "<Resourcegroup name>";
$webAppName = "<WebApp name>";
$Apiversion = 2015-08-01

#Function to get Publishing credentials for the WebApp :
function Get-PublishingProfileCredentials($resourceGroupName, $webAppName){

$resourceType = "Microsoft.Web/sites/config"
$resourceName = "$webAppName/publishingcredentials"
$publishingCredentials = Invoke-AzResourceAction -ResourceGroupName $resourceGroupName -ResourceType 
$resourceType -ResourceName $resourceName -Action list -ApiVersion $Apiversion -Force
   return $publishingCredentials
}

#Pulling authorization access token :
function Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue($resourceGroupName, $webAppName){

$publishingCredentials = Get-PublishingProfileCredentials $resourceGroupName $webAppName
return ("Basic {0}" -f [Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(("{0}:{1}" -f 
$publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingUserName, $publishingCredentials.Properties.PublishingPassword))))
}

$accessToken = Get-KuduApiAuthorisationHeaderValue $resourceGroupName $webAppname
#Generating header to create and publish the Webjob :
$Header = @{
'Content-Disposition'='attachment; attachment; filename=Copy.zip'
'Authorization'=$accessToken
        }
$apiUrl = "https://$webAppName.scm.azurewebsites.net/api/<Webjob-type>/<Webjob-name>"
$result = Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $apiUrl -Headers $Header -Method put -InFile "<Complete path of the file>\
<filename>.zip" -ContentType 'application/zip'
```